# gnome "switch user" shortcut or command line

Tags: bash, centos, gnome, users

Is it possible to switch user of gnome desktop environment by single command or any shortcut key, in centos 6.0, or Can we create shortcut key?

I found "[fusa](http://jcape.name/fusa/)", but still unable to install it.

Answer (score 0):

If `gdmflexiserver` is available on CentOS 6 it might do what you want.

Comment: It's available in Lubuntu after installing `libgdm1`, but it raises this error: `** (gdmflexiserver:22633): WARNING **: Unable to create transient display: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.DisplayManager was not provided by any .service files
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.DisplayManager was not provided by any .service files`